# image change like show/hide when i use a toggle script on the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could anyone give me solution what method to use when i click an image like black x then show a div and after i click again image it's change into red x and hide div?

```
$(".open").click(function(){
        if ($(this).text()=="open")
            $(this).text("close")
            else
                $(this).text("open")
                $("div").toggle(300);
    });
```

this is for change text on button and toggle a div if i use 2 different type of image instead of button what i change in this code.

Comment: post you html in the question

Comment: Sorry Mr. Jain i cant understand what are you want?

Comment: I show you my html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `.text()` of the button, add a semantic class to the element:

```
$(".open").click(function(){
    if ($(this).is("isopen")
        $(this).removeClass("isopen").addClass("isclosed")
    else
        $(this).removeClass("isclosed").addClass("isopen")
    $("#mydiv").toggle(300);
});
```

you can then change the image using background image css

```
.isopen {
    background-image:url('openimage.png');
}
.isclosed {
    background-image:url('closedimage.png');
}
```

or you could change the image src

If you don't want to use background images, an alternative (and generally easier to understand/follow) option is to have two separate elements for the toggle - one for on and one for off - and then show/hide them accordingly, eg:

```
<div class='show'><img...></div>
<div class='close' style='display:none;'><img...></div>
```

(make sure the images are the same size...)

```
$(".show").click(function() {
    $(".show").hide();
    $(".hide").show();
    $("#mydiv").show();
}
$(".hide").click(function() {
    $(".hide").hide();
    $(".show").show();
    $("#mydiv").hide();
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not able to convince actually i have 2 image an image. But i can't show in my html i write a jquery with these 2 image on click method.

Comment: like this:    $(function(){
   $('.close').click(function(){
   if($('.close').html() == '<img src="close.png">') {
   $('.close').html('<img src="close2.png">');
   $('.banner').hide(500);
   }
            
   else{
   $('.banner').show(500);
   $('.close').html('<img src="close.png">');
   }
   });
  });

Comment: but this is to long method

Comment: any idea how i short this method

Comment: Why is your code too long?   It seems neat and clear what it does.  Do you need to repeat multiple times (so seems too long)?  You could create a function or use relative paths etc, but we'd need to know your html to help with that.